# Upgrade Sitecore 9.1 to Version 10.1.1

Tags: azure, upgrade

We have Sitecore 9.1.1 currently deployed on production environment.
Our topology is scaled on Azure App services.

It's required to upgrade current version (9.1.1) to the latest Sitecore version (10.1.1) and deploy it on scaled azure topology (using App Services)

We have visited the [official product page - Sitecore XP 10.1 Update-1](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/101/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_101_Update1.aspx) and explored [this guide](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/4F6A089B8A574C82A3CE107C0BE8A311.ashx?date=20210615T084212) BUT it's not mentioning anything about "App Services" option!

Now, I'm looking for a step-by-step guide that we can follow to upgrade Sitecore 9.1.1 to version 10.1.1 on Azure app service scaled environment .. How to move forward ?

Answer (score 3):

Besides following the Sitecore [upgrade guide](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/185FB45E3F1E49AD8B7F5263FBEE46FA.ashx?date=20210601T144510), in order to upgrade SXA you should follow the SXA [upgrade guide](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/26BFC502BC014AF6A0E885A426C79DC7.ashx?date=20210225T115812) on the page https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/10x/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_1010.aspx

The section "2.2.4 Remove obsolete module content" is reffering to old sitecore modules which are obsolete, for example WFFM. Make sure to check if you are using any sitecore or custom modules and see if they are compatible with the latest sitecore version.

Regarding Azure App Services, you should take into consideration that it will be completely removed in the future and it will be supported until 10.2. Please read the sitecore documentation regarding sitecore on azure https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/sitecore-on-azure.html.

Comment: I've explored SXA upgrade guide. BUT, the part "1.2 Installing the package" is really confusing. If I have clean Sitecore 10.1.1, why I should delete *.XA.* files? and Should I delete the items under "Core DB" before running DB upgrade scripts .. Please elaborate on that part

Comment: If you deploy a fresh instance you don't have to delete the files as they won't be there, but depending on how you do the deploys you will need to update the files in your git repo aswell. The same for the core db items, in case you have them serialized. As stated in the sitecore documentation you have to do these steps before doing the SXA install.

Comment: Well, Consider the following scenario: 1- Install fresh instance of 10.1.1    2- Backup Master, Core... etc DB of 9.1.1     3- Run Upgrade scripts on the old DBs    4- Connect the instance of 10.1.1 to the upgraded DBs.          5- Install SXA 10.1        that's it?  Where exactly the step of deleting Core DB items should come ?

Comment: In this scenario, as stated in the upgrade guide you should remove the core items from the db before installing SXA 10.1. I think you can also remove them also before running the db upgrade scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions and use this guide [Upgrade guide to Sitecore 10.1](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/185FB45E3F1E49AD8B7F5263FBEE46FA.ashx?date=20210601T144510)

Use [Sitecore 10.1.1 artifacts](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/101/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_101_Update1.aspx)  and update your sitecore in all app service instances in Azure.

Basically you use 10.1.1 files but use 10.1 upgrade guide, since 10.1.x doesnt have breaking changes there for you use 10.1 upgrade guide.

Comment: The documentation did not position "SXA upgrade step".. should it be Pre or Post DB Upgrade?

Comment: and regarding "2.2.4 Remove obsolete module content" .. Does it mean "uninstalling SXA" ?